# My combination of 'post_type' and 'tax_query' not working?

Tags: wp-query, filters, search

I want to filter search results by custom post type and custom taxonomy terms, the result is here:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
function search_filter($query) {
    if($query->query_vars['s'] != '' && is_search())
    {
        $query->set('post_type', array('partner','event','product'));
        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'belgrade' )
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Posts from specific CPT works, but filter by a category, not.
Why? :)

Comment: `is_search` always refers to `$wp_query->is_search()`, but what if `$query` is not the main query? Then the if statement won't match because `$query->is_search()` might be true, but `is_search()` will be false! Otherwise the result of this appears to be that you want to search 3 post types, but _only_ the posts that are in the city of belgrade

Comment: I want to be safe to filter query only on the search page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is you're using the **relation** where you only have one inner tax array. So, it should be without one.

```
$tax_query = array(
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'city',
         'field'    => 'slug',
         'terms'    => array( 'belgrade' )
   )
);
```

Here's a detailed explanation from WP: [Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

- **relation (string)** – The logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one. Possible values are ‘AND’, ‘OR’. Do not use with a single inner taxonomy array.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this broke search, as a result, I don’t get a cpt results as before.